# Why is the ContentObserver called multiple times?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, contentobserver

I have following `ContentObserver` implementation for receiving and writing SMS, but it is called multiple times.

Code:

```
public class SMSObserverActivity extends Activity {
    protected MyContentObserver observer = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String url = "content://mms-sms/";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        observer = new MyContentObserver(new Handler());
        getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(uri, true, observer);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();

        getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(observer);
    }

    class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        Handler handler;

        public MyContentObserver(Handler handler){
            super(handler);
            this.handler = handler;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean deliverSelfNotifications(){
            return false;
        }


        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean arg0){
            super.onChange(arg0);

            Log.v("SMS", "Notification on SMS observer");
            values.put("status", 5);
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.obj = "xxxxxxxxxx";
            int threadId = 0;
            handler.sendMessage(msg);

            Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
            Cursor cur =
                    getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,
                            null);
            cur.moveToNext();
            Log.e("sms", cur.getString(4)+" "+cur.getString(11));
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".SMSObserverActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Why is it called multiple times?

EDIT:
There was the idea that the problem is caused by the missing `unregisterContentObserver`, but it makes no difference.

Comment: Not yet, I haven't the time for it yet, but read the comments on the answer and try it with a service. Perhaps you will get it working. ;)

Comment: The issue is the same if run in a Service I'm afraid

Comment: Yeh same issue occurs, I have found the cause of it though. See answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is occurring because you are registering your content observer for the entire SMS database. So your content observer gets notified each time a table entry in the database gets updated.

In this case when a message is sent for example around 7 tables entries get updated so your content observer gets notified 7 times.

Since I'm only interested if a message is sent I've changed to only observe the queued messages and this means my observer always gets notified exactly three times so I have implemented code to protect against that.

There are likely to be some other issues such as multi recipient or multi part messages but the basics work so far.

Comment: Okay I thought the observer is only called one time for all related updates per object. I think there is an unique ID to see, which notifications belongs to one update, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid sending multiple sms by content observer try this

```
public class SmsObserver extends ContentObserver {
    SharedPreferences trackMeData;
    private Context context;
    private static int initialPos;
    private static final String TAG = "SMSContentObserver";
    private static final Uri uriSMS = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");

    public SmsObserver(Handler handler, Context ctx) {
        super(handler);
        context = ctx;
        trackMeData = context.getSharedPreferences("LockedSIM", 0);
        initialPos = getLastMsgId();

    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        queryLastSentSMS();
    }

    public int getLastMsgId() {

        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSMS, null, null, null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        int lastMsgId = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        Log.i(TAG, "Last sent message id: " + String.valueOf(lastMsgId));
        return lastMsgId;
    }

    protected void queryLastSentSMS() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Cursor cur =
                    context.getContentResolver().query(uriSMS, null, null, null, null);

                if (cur.moveToNext()) {



                    try {

                        String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));

                        if (initialPos != getLastMsgId()) {

                            String receiver = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
                            Log.i("account", myDeviceId);
                            Log.i("date", day + "-" + month + "-" + year + " "
                                + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + seconde);
                            Log.i("sender", myTelephoneNumber);
                            Log.i("receiver", receiver );


                            // Then, set initialPos to the current position.
                            initialPos = getLastMsgId();

                            sendsmstoph(receiver, body);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // Treat exception here
                    }
                }
                cur.close();
            }
        }).start();

    }
```

Comment: Calling initialPos = getLastMsgId(); from contructor throws null pointer exception

Comment: I have noticed that this is good but not always fool proof. So I think that using SharedPreferences can solve this problem. Here's how I have done it:
if (!sharedPreferences.getString("lastMessageTime", "0")
                                    .equals(String.valueOf(timeInMillis))
                                    || !sharedPreferences.getString("lastMessageNumber", "0")
                                    .equals(number))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your observer enabled only when the activity is in active state, I advise you to move `registerContentObserver()` and `unregisterContentObserver()` to methods `onResume()` and `onPause()` respectively. `onDestroy()` may not be called if your application exits, but `onPause()` is guaranteed to be.

Comment: The observer shall be always active, when the *Activity* is running. It is just a observing content test.

Comment: Activity is running between `onResume()` and `onPause()`, in the other time it is either in background or not visible. It may even get killed without getting a call to `onDestroy()`, and when you recreate application in `onCreate()`, you will register an observer for the second time.

Comment: Why shall it registered two times? I have an unregister statement.

Comment: You have it in `onDestroy()` method, and it is not guaranteed to be called. The method which gets called when your activity stops running (goes off the screen) is `onPause()`. From documentation about `onDestroy()`: "there are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it".

Comment: Okay I have tried it now with a static class member, which contains the observer. It makes no difference. Using `onResume()` and `onPause()` isn't suitable for me, because I want to start the `Activity` and after that I send a sms to me.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't quite get why do you think that making observer static would make difference? And if you want to receive events while activity is in the background, then you shouldn't use an activity, you should use a service.

Answer (score 0):

**Cheap hack**

You are currently overriding the `onChange` method with the boolean parameter.

I circumvented the same problem by simple overriding the one that takes in the `Uri` so that you could compare them.

Illustration (Kotlin):

```
private var latestImageUri: String = ""

 contentObserver = object : ContentObserver(Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())) {
        override fun onChange(selfChange: Boolean, uri: Uri?) {
            super.onChange(selfChange, uri)

            if (latestImageUri != uri.toString()) {
                latestImageUri = uri.toString()
                
                //Continue with your code
```